# How To Start Script As Soon as Possible On Boot?

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I want to use Systemd (Systemctl) to launch a program immediately after Systemd is launched. Even before the device establishes an Internet connection or network. For reference this is a Raspberry Pi and I want to turn on the 16x2 LCD display with text as soon as possible after the Raspbian based OS has booted up. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

add the desired command/script to execute when the OS boots up by modifying the .xinitrc file. 
Read more about modifying OS start functionality here.
https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xinit